# While clicking on the submit button,the user is not navigated to the next page in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was automating a Web application for shopping.
In a particular page I have to submit by clicking on the submit button. I coded in selenium web driver for the same thing to happen.
The button was clicked but it never navigated to the next page and it doesn't throw any exception and I could see the test run successfully.

```
package org.karmaloop.testcase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.karmaloop.configuration.Testconfiguration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

@RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class testcase1 {

    private static ChromeDriverService srv;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void StartServer() throws IOException {
        // Below file path to Chrome browser should be changed accordingly
        srv = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingDriverExecutable(
                        new File("D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe"))
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        srv.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before()
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(srv.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {


        Normal_Checkout();

    }

    private void Normal_Checkout() throws Exception {

        //To get commented  

          driver.get("https://m.karmaloop.com/product/The-Superstar-80s-GRF-Sneaker-in-Wheat-Black-Chalk/384883");
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Testconfiguration.size_dropdown)).click();
          System.out.println("success");
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.select_size)).click();
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.addtocart_button)).click();
          Thread.sleep(7000);


          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.pcheckout_button)).click();
          Thread.sleep(5000);

            // To get commented   

          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.checkout_logintxtbox)).sendKeys(Testconfiguration.checkout_login_username);
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.checkout_passwordtxtbox)).sendKeys(Testconfiguration.checkout_login_password);
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.checkout_loginbtn)).click();
          Thread.sleep(10000);
          System.out.println("Passed before checkout");
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(Testconfiguration.submit_button));
          Thread.sleep(20000);
          System.out.println("submit clicked");
          }}
```

==================================================================================
I have used xpath to for the submit button to get clicked. Can anyone help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: It would help if you could please provide the relevant HTML snippet and showing the actually xpath you have used within the `Testconfiguration.submit_button` call. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please do yourself a huge favor: go read up on explicit waits and stop using Thread.sleep(). You're costing yourself huge amounts of time (HOURS over a large suite of tests) with all these delays.  Even if you're just stubbing out something for a prototype -- avoid Thread.sleep().

Comment: Have you tried the same with selenium IDE.What about other types of locators such as CSS.Generally CSS tends to be more stabler than XPath if the content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this this issue when working with selenium before, and while I don't have a solution, I do have a work around that works the majority of the time.

After you click the submit button, if you try to interact with an element on the next page Selenium should through an NoSuchElementException. Catch this and attempt to reclick the submit button (since you can assume that the page did not load). Nine times out of ten this works for me.

Oh and a tip you might find useful, instead of manually waiting for five seconds after every time you load a page, use [implicitlyWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html). browser.implicitlyWait(30) will have the browser wait up to 30 seconds for the page to load before throwing a NoSuchElementException.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Edit: I might be mistaken, I believe its recommended that you don't use XPath as your selector unless you absolutely have to, as it is much slower than the alternatives (like ID) since it has to walk through the XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the page is loaded.

Example:

```
//wait until page is loaded
String title = "Should have the title of the page that should be loaded";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(title));
```

This code will wait for 60 seconds until the page title matches with the one passed as input.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing an issue, where it was clicking an element but it was not redirecting to the next page and was not getting an exception also. I tried with Actions class, Javascript executor, Robot class and all the wait statements, but I was not getting the result. This solution worked for me.

```
try {
      //Next page element
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='web']/label/span[contains(text(), 'Congratulations!')]")).click();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    //current page element which is not redirecting after performing click operation
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-main-container']/button")).click();
        }
```

***You have to try to interact with an element on the next page and use the XPath for the element in the try block and the XPath for the element which is not redirected to next page in a catch block.***